# Excel Interop Pivot column field goes to row

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, pivot-table, excel-interop

I am working on creating a Pivot table programmatically in a Windows Application. I have the below code that is assigning the columns to their respective fields. My problem arises with Region 2, which I want to be assigned to the column field but for some reason, it keeps going to the rowfield.
As you will see, I have 1 row, 1 column, 1 page and 2 data fields written in the code.

```
ExcelRef.Worksheet SourceSheet = ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
ExcelRef.Worksheet TargetSheet = ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After: ExcelWorkbook.Sheets[ExcelWorkbook.Sheets.Count]);

//Pivot data source
ExcelRef.Range SourceDataRange = SourceSheet.UsedRange;
//Clearing the destination sheet
TargetSheet.UsedRange.Clear();
//Pivot Data destination
ExcelRef.Range PivotDestination = TargetSheet.get_Range("A1");

string PivotTableName = "Sample";

ExcelWorkbook.PivotTableWizard(ExcelRef.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,
SourceDataRange,
PivotDestination,
PivotTableName,
true, true, true, true,
useDefault, useDefault,
false, false,
ExcelRef.XlOrder.xlDownThenOver,
0,
useDefault, useDefault);

//Pivot cell arrangement
ExcelRef.PivotTable TempPivotTable = TargetSheet.PivotTables(PivotTableName);
ExcelRef.PivotField Region1 = TempPivotTable.PivotFields(14);
ExcelRef.PivotField Region2 = TempPivotTable.PivotFields(15);
ExcelRef.PivotField Region3 = TempPivotTable.PivotFields(19);
ExcelRef.PivotField Region4 = TempPivotTable.PivotFields(20);
ExcelRef.PivotField Region5 = TempPivotTable.PivotFields(23);

Region1.Orientation = ExcelRef.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
Region1.Position = 1;
Region2.Orientation = ExcelRef.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;  //Problem with this region
Region2.Position = 1;
Region3.Orientation = ExcelRef.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;
Region4.Orientation = ExcelRef.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
Region4.Position = 1;
Region4.Function = ExcelRef.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum;
Region5.Orientation = ExcelRef.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
Region5.Position = 2;
Region5.Function = ExcelRef.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum;
```

Where am I going wrong? How do I resolve this?

**[Edit]**
Fun Fact: Just to get a better insight, I changed the xlRowField to xlColumnField as well, in hopes that the two regions would get assigned to the columns but no luck. They still work as Rows. This noob is out of tricks. Please help.

Comment: The code you posted is not enough to identify the cause of the problem. Please post a snippet including `RegionX` declaration and initialization.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have added more code. That's all the code that I am using related to the pivot table

Comment: Sorry, everything looks fine in this code, I have no idea what could be the problem.